# checkbox validation for sign up page using bootstrapvalidator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to validate checkbox which has value "I agree to the terms and conditions" in the sign-up page using bootstrapvalidator plugin.If the checkbox is not checked appropriate message should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily with jquery. (Wich you should have included if using Bootstrap).

```
if($("#checkbox").is(':checked')) {  
    alert("Welcome");  
} else {  
    alert("You must agree to the ToS");  
}
```

Here's more on that: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link [Bootstrap Validation](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/attribute/) and Fire validation on submit button.